# Last Timestamps of last 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to take the last timestamp of each product for each day for last 7 days. There are thousands of records in database. How can I do that with a query. There are around 25 distinct products and each product has around 50 timestamps per day.

Table: BuildData

```
 'Timestamp'    |  'Product' | 'BuildNo'

'2015-10-21 12:12:00', 'AB', '809'
'2015-10-21 13:12:00', 'AB', '44'
'2015-10-21 12:12:00', 'CD', '408'
'2015-10-21 13:12:00', 'CD', '15'
'2015-10-21 12:12:00', 'ABC', '1699'
'2015-10-21 13:12:00', 'ABC', '1051'
'2015-10-21 14:12:00', 'ABC', '66'
'2015-10-21 15:12:00', 'ABC', '120'
'2015-10-21 13:12:00', 'XYZ', '928'
'2015-10-21 13:12:00', 'XYZ', '37'
'2015-10-21 16:12:00', 'XYZ', '137'
```

Comment: Did you attempt to resolve the requirement at all? if yes, show us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You grab all the dates in your table by using `DATE()` to covert your timestamps.  Then group the date and product columns together and run `MAX()` on the timestamp column to get the last timestamp of each day for every one of your products.

```
SELECT DATE(Timestamp) AS Date, Product, MAX(Timestamp) AS Last_timestamp
FROM Builddata
WHERE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and NOW();
GROUP BY Date, Product
```

Comment: Op also asked for a `where` clause - "last 7 days". `where timestamp > date_sub(CURDATE(),interval 7 day)` will do.

Comment: @Timekiller Thanks, I forgot that part

Comment: @Lloyd Banks - It only gives the last time stamp of one product. Output has to include 7 timestamps (last timestamp of each day) for each product. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: @ThilinaAkalanka no it isn't, check this out - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/287e6/4 . Your sample input only contains one date, that might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
Timestamp,
Product,
BuildNo
from Yourtable
inner join 
-- Selecting max data per product per day
(Select max(timestamp) as MaxTimestamp, Product as MaxProduct from yourTBL 
-- You only want the data for the last 7 days
where datediff(timestamp,current_timestamp)<7
group by Product, date_add(0,INTERVAL (datediff(0,timestamp)) DAY  )MaxTbl
on MaxProduct = Product and MaxTimestamp=Timestamp
```

Comment: @ Andrej Can you explain this query a bit